# Dynamically add equal select form fields with data taken from php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, select

I have a form with select fields dynamically generated and with the options taken from php (same for all the selects). But I need that every `<select>...</select>` must be shown in a different line. This can be done having every `<select>...</select>` inside a `<div>...</div>`.

This is the code that I have, it´s working but the select fields are not within a div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
var counter = 1;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
        return false;
}   

var select = $('<select>').attr({id:'select'+counter,name:'select'+counter});

$.ajax({
url: 'selects.php',
dataType: "html",
success: function(data) {
select.html(data);
}
});        

select.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
counter++;
});

$("#removeButton").click(function () {
if(counter==1){
   alert("No more textbox to remove");
   return false;
}   

counter--;
$("#select" + counter).remove();

});

$("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

var msg = '';
for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
  msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
}
   alert(msg);
});
});
//]]> 
</script>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='text' id='textbox1' >
</div>
<div id="TextBoxDiv2">
    <label>Textbox #2 : </label><input type='text' id='textbox2' >
</div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```

And this is the html code generated by select.php:

```
<option value="1">Uno</option>
<option value="2">Dos</option>
<option value="3">Tres</option>
<option value="4">Cuatro</option>
```

Comment: amparo69, you should roll back the edits to how the question was posed and answered for the original issue.  This would be about version 5.  It's frowned-upon to mutate the nature of a question too much. (Ask a new question instead.)  I've rolled this question back for you.  Next I'll go look at the new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the `wrap()` function](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=wrap). :

Put this code just before the `counter++;`. :

```
$("#TextBoxesGroup > select").wrap ( function () {
    return '<div id="wrap_' + this.id + '"></div>';
} );
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/YLAJn/6/)

Comment: It doesn´t work well. I nedd that every <select>...</select> must be inside a <div id="x">...</div>.

The code Im using is:
    select.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
     $("#TextBoxesGroup select").wrap ( function () {
        return '<div id= ' + this.id + '></div>';
    } );
just before the counter++; It works but it adds more and more divs to the previous selects so the selects are not shown well alligned to the left and not one select in each line.

Comment: See the updated answer.  Also remember that no 2 elements can have the same `id` without bad things happening.

Comment: Great! It´s now working. Thanks very much. But in needs:
select.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
just before your posted code. Please update it to have it perfect for everybody.

Comment: Julst one last thing. The remove button is not working perfectly. If you click "remove", the select dissapears, but then if you click "add", the new select appears below the removed one, not just in the position of the removed one. I have tried with $("#select" + counter).remove(); and $("#wrap_" + counter).remove(); and it´s the same.

Comment: It´s not removing everything when you click remove so then when you add again, it appears below the ideal position.

Comment: That's a separate question; please open a new one for that.  (Questions should be single-issue, as much as possible, and should not change midstream (except to clarify, as needed).)

Comment: Ok, let´s open a new question abut the same code. I'll wait you there XD

Comment: Paste-in the current/modified version of the code you are using.  Also linking to the page and/or a jsFiddle is always good.  (But never link *instead* of posting code; always *in addition to*.)